# How to remove the repetition of new lines?

Tags: python, scrapy

When I run this code, it gives me one word and then leave the whole line and this process repeats till the end. I want it to be in a `row` not in `columns`.

```
import scrapy
from .. items import FetchingItem
import re

class SiteFetching(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Site'

    def start_requests(self):
        links = [('https://www.rev.com/freelancers/subtitles', self.parse_subtitles)]

        return [scrapy.Request(link[0], callback=link[1]) for link in links]

    def parse_subtitles(self, response):
        subtitles = FetchingItem()
        Subtitles_price = response.css('.rate::text , .language::text').extract()
        Subtitles_price = [re.sub(r'[\r\n\s]+', ' ', text) for text in Subtitles_price]

        subtitles['Subtitles_price'] = Subtitles_price

        yield subtitles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't `str.strip()` work? Something like:

```
subtitles_price = [text.strip() for text in subtitles_price]
```

It may have several prices, in this case you could use:

```
subtitles_price = ", ".join([text.strip() for text in subtitles_price])
```

You could also use `str.lstrip()` or `str.rstrip()` to remove new line chars only from the beginning or ending of a string